# Can I use a stackful coroutine as the wait handler of a steady_timer which is defined inside the very stackful coroutine?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Can I use stackful coroutine and `boost::asio::steady_timer::async_wait` in the following way?
The point is that (my understanding, not sure) during waiting, local variable `timer` is not on the stack and thus inaccessible. So can the callback proceed normally? (FYI, it works fine on my Mac using clang++5.0 .)

```
boost::asio::io_service io;
void Work(boost::asio::yield_context yield) {
  boost::asio::steady_timer timer(io);

  timer.expires_from_now(std::chrono::seconds(5));
  timer.async_wait(yield);

  cout << "Woke up." << endl;
}

int main() {
  boost::asio::spawn(io, Work);
  io.run();
  return 0;
}
```

I think it is worth a comparison between this question: [boost asio deadline_timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539583/boost-asio-deadline-timer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to pass `boost::asio::yield_context` to an object that has automatic storage duration within the same coroutine.

[Boost.Coroutine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/index.html) uses [Boost.Context](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/context/doc/html/index.html) to perform context switching.  Boost.Context provides a means to suspend the current execution path, preserving the stack (including local variables such as `Work()`'s `timer`), and transfer execution control, allowing the same thread to run with a different stack.  Hence, with the `boost::asio::steady_timer` object having automatic storage duration, its lifespan will end when either:

- control exits the block specified by `Work()` via either a `return`, reaching end of function, or an exception unwinding the stack.
- The associated `io_service` is destroyed.  Internal handlers maintain shared ownership of the coroutine, and when the `io_service` is destroyed, all associated handlers are also destroyed.  This destruction will cause Boost.Coroutine to force each coroutine's stack to unwind.

When [`boost::asio::spawn()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/spawn.html) is invoked, Boost.Asio performs some setup work and then will [dispatch()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/dispatch.html) an internal handler that will create a coroutine using the user provided function as an entry point.  When the `yield_context` object is passed as a handler to asynchronous operations, Boost.Asio will *yield* immediately after initiating the asynchronous operation with a completion handler that will copy results and *resume* the coroutine.  A [`strand`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html) owned by the coroutine is used to guarantee the *yield* occurs before *resume*.  Here is an attempt to illustrate the execution of the example code:

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::spawn(io_service, &Work);
`-- dispatch a coroutine creator
    into the io_service.
io_service.run();
|-- invoke the coroutine creator
|   handler.
|   |-- create and jump into
|   |   into coroutine         ----> Work()
:   :                                |-- timer created
:   :                                |-- setting timer expiration
:   :                                |-- timer.async_wait(yield)
:   :                                |   |-- create error_code on stack
:   :                                |   |-- initiate async_wait operation,
:   :                                |   |   passing in completion handler that
:   :                                |   |   will resume the coroutine
|   `-- return                 <---- |   |-- yield
|-- io_service has work (the         :   :
|   async_wait operation)            :   :
|   ...async wait completes...       :   :
|-- invoke completion handler        :   :
|   |-- copies error_code            :   :
|   |   provided by service          :   :
|   |   into the one on the          :   :
|   |   coroutine stack              :   :
|   |-- resume                 ----> |   `-- return error code
:   :                                |-- cout << "Waked up." << endl;
:   :                                |-- exiting Work() block, timer is 
:   :                                |   destroyed.
|   `-- return                 <---- `-- coroutine done, yielding
`-- no outstanding work in 
    io_service, return.
```

Comment: @updogliu Execution can be transferred between multiple coroutines within a single thread.  See the [motivation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/coroutine/motivation.html) for Boost.Coroutine for examples.

Comment: Is the unwinding of a `Coroutine`'s stacks (because of `io_service` is destroyed or other reasons) also wrapped in the `strand` which the `Coroutine` executes in?

Comment: @updogliu When control exits the block by either `return` or reaching the end of the function, the coroutine's stack unwinds within the context of the handler's `strand`.  When the `io_service` is destroyed, the coroutine's stack unwinds outside of the `strand`.  For coroutines, the `strand`'s primary purpose is to guarantee the _yield_ finishes before _resume_ is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

yes - it should work.
boost::asio::steady_timer timer(io) registers the timer on the io-service.

Comment: Do you mean `timer` is not needed anymore after `async_wait` is called?