# Can a boost::asio::yield_context be used as a deadline_timer handler when doing cancel?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'd like to be able to do an asynchronous wait on a specific event.  There are a lot of similar questions and answers on here (and all compile and work for me) but none with my specific scenario.  Basically, what I need to be able to do is an async_wait, passing a yield context as the handler, to a timer that waits indefinitely, and is then canceled by another thread.

For example, there is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005258/why-does-boost-asio-not-support-an-event-based-interface-for-example-something#) which does something very similar, but instead of using a yield context, it uses a separate, standalone handler.  There is also something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21771639/can-i-use-a-stackful-coroutine-as-the-wait-handler-of-a-steady-timer-which-is-de) which uses a yield context, but waits for a specified amount of time.

I can change my code to look like either of the two examples above and things work fine.  But for someone reason when I combine a yield_context handler and a cancelled timer, I get the following exception:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::current_exception_std_exception_wrapper<std::runtime_error> >: 
Program ended with exit code: 9
```

From what I can tell, it looks like things choke when trying to invoke the completion handler (which in this case is the yield context).

Alright, enough babbling, here's the code.  I've tried to come up with as simple of an example as possible to illustrate it:

The class:

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo() : work_(io_service_), timer_(io_service_) {
    thread_pool_.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service_));
    timer_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::pos_infin);
  }
  ~Foo() {
    io_service_.stop();
    thread_pool_.join_all();
  }

  void Wait(const boost::asio::yield_context& context) {
    std::cout << "Waiting" << std::endl;
    timer_.async_wait(context);
    std::cout << "Done waiting" << std::endl;
  }

  void Notify() {
    std::cout << "Notifying" << std::endl;
    timer_.cancel();
  }

  void Write(int num) {
    std::cout << "Sending buffer event" << std::endl;
    Notify();
    std::cout << "Sent buffer event" << std::endl;
  }

  void Read(const boost::asio::yield_context& context) {
    std::cout << "Waiting on buffer event, size is " << buffer_.size() << std::endl;
    Wait(context);
    std::cout << "Received buffer event, size is now " << buffer_.size() << std::endl;
  }

  std::vector<int> buffer_;
  boost::asio::io_service io_service_;
  boost::thread_group thread_pool_;
  boost::asio::io_service::work work_;
  boost::asio::deadline_timer timer_;
};
```

Main:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Foo> foo(new Foo());    
boost::asio::spawn(foo->io_service_, boost::bind(&Foo::Read, foo, _1));
boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(2));
foo->Write(1);
boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(4));
```

Output:

```
Waiting on buffer event
Waiting
Sending buffer event
Notifying
Sent buffer event
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::current_exception_std_exception_wrapper<std::runtime_error> >:
```

Now, if I change the wait method to a time that will time out before the cancel is called, everything is fine.  I.e.:

```
void Wait(const boost::asio::yield_context& context) {
    std::cout << "Waiting" << std::endl;
    timer_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
    timer_.async_wait(context);
    std::cout << "Done waiting" << std::endl;
  }
```

Or, if I change wait to use a separate handler method, everything is fine.  I.e.:

```
void Handler() {
  std::cout << "Handler!" << std::endl;
}

void Wait(const boost::asio::yield_context& context) {       
  std::cout << "Waiting" << std::endl;
  timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&Foo::Handler, this));
  std::cout << "Done waiting" << std::endl;
}
```

I'm assuming there must be something simpler I'm missing here: either this is impossible for some reason or I'm making some dumb mistake.  Anyway, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `async_wait()` operation is being [cancelled](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/cancel/overload1.html), resulting in the asynchronous operation failing with an error code of `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted`.  As noted in the [Stackful Coroutines documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/spawn.html), when the `boost::asio::yield_context` detects that the asynchronous operation has failed, it converts the `boost::system::error_code` into a `system_error` exception and throws.  Within the coroutine, consider either:

- Initiating the asynchronous operation with a handler of [`context[error_code]`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_yield_context/operator_lb__rb_.html), causing the `yield_context` to populate the provided `boost::system::error_code` on failure rather than throwing.

  ```cpp
  boost::system::error_code error;
  timer_.async_wait(context[error]); // On failure, populate error.
  ```
- Catch the `system_error` and suppress it.

---

On failure Boost.Asio will populate a `boost::system::error_code` if the application is capable of receiving it, otherwise it will throw an exception.  This pattern can be observed throughout Boost.Asio:

- All [asynchronous operation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asynchronous_operations.html) handler's accept an lvalue `const boost::system::error_code` as their first parameter.  Hence, the initiating function should not throw, as the application will be informed of the error within the handler.  This is not always apparent when using functors that discards extra arguments, such as [`boost::bind`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bind/bind.html).
- Synchronous operations are overloaded to support throwing and non-throwing versions.  For example, [`timer.cancel()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/cancel/overload1.html) will throw on failure, where as [`timer.cancel(boost::system::error_code&)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/cancel/overload2.html) will set the `error_code` to indicate the error.
- As noted above, when an asynchronous operation fails within a stackful coroutine and the [`yield_context`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_yield_context.html) handler is not provided a `boost::system::error_code`, then a `system_error` exception will be thrown.
- When using [futures](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/cpp2011/futures.html), if the asynchronous operation fails, then the `error_code` is converted into a `system_error` exception and passed back to the caller through the `future`.

---

Here is a complete minimal example based on the original problem that runs to completion.

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io_service);
  timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::pos_infin);

  boost::asio::spawn(io_service,
    [&](boost::asio::yield_context yield)
    {
      // As only one thread is processing the io_service, the posted
      // timer cancel will only be invoked once the coroutine yields.
      io_service.post([&](){ timer.cancel(); });

      // Initiate an asynchronous operation, suspending the current coroutine,
      // and allowing the io_service to process other work (i.e. cancel the 
      // timer).  When the timer is cancelled, the asynchronous operation is
      // completed with an error,  causing the coroutine to resume.  As an
      // error_code is provided, the operation will not throw on failure.
      boost::system::error_code error;
      timer.async_wait(yield[error]);
      assert(error == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted);
    });

  io_service.run();
}
```

Comment: Awesome...Thanks for the clear, excellent response and all of the extra context!